# Sign of the error in Simpson's rule

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ function.  The Riemann integral $I = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ can be approximated by using [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_rule):
$$I \approx S = \frac{b-a}{6} \left[ f(a) + 4 f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) + f(b) \right]$$
The error in this approximation is known to be controlled by the fourth derivative of $f$: 
$$|I-S| \le \frac{1}{90} \left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^5 \sup_{[a,b]} |f^{(4)}|.$$

Now with some other approximation rules for integrals, we can, under certain conditions, say something about the sign of the error.  For instance, if one uses the left endpoint approximation $L = (b-a) f(a)$, then if $f$ is increasing ($f' \ge 0$) we have $L \le I$.  Likewise, using the midpoint approximation $M = (b-a) f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$, it can be shown that if $f$ is concave up ($f'' \ge 0$) then we have $M \le I$.

Are there any simple conditions on $f$ that guarantee $S \le I$ (or vice versa)?  For instance, does it happen if the fourth derivative $f^{(4)}$ has a definite sign?

It would be particularly nice if this condition were "stable under subdivision".  That is, given any subdivision $\pi = \{a = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_n = b\}$, we can form a Simpson's rule approximation of the integral:
$$I \approx S_\pi = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_n - x_{n-1}}{6} \left[ f(x_{n-1}) + 4 f\left(\frac{x_{n-1} + x_n}{2}\right) + f(x_n)\right].$$
I would be especially interested in any condition that guarantees $S_{\pi} \le I$ for every $\pi$.  (Analogously, having $f$ be an increasing function guarantees the corresponding fact for the left endpoint rule, as does concave up for the midpoint rule.)

Comment: Actually no, I'm wrong about my previous comment, because the error is given by $\int_a^b \frac{f^{(3)}(c(x))}{6} (x-a)(x-b)(x-c) dx$, where $c(x)$ can be anywhere in the interval. So I've retracted my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Set $x=(a+b)/2$, $h=(b-a)/2$ and consider 
$$
\frac{6\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(t)dt-2h(f(x+h)+4f(x)+f(x-h))}{h^5}
$$
as a function in $h$ and apply the extended mean value theorem repeatedly to get
\begin{align}
&=\frac{4f(x+h_1)-8f(x)+4f(x-h_1)-2h_1(f'(x+h_1)-f'(x-h_1))}{5h_1^4}\\[1em]
&=\frac{2f'(x+h_2)-2f'(x-h_2)-2h_2(f''(x+h_2)+f''(x-h_2))}{20h_2^3}
\\ \\
&=\frac{2h_3(f'''(x+h_3)-f'''(x-h_3))}{60h_3^2}=\frac1{15}·\frac{f'''(x+h_3)-f'''(x-h_3)}{2h_3}
\\ \\
&=\frac1{15}·f^{(4)}(x+h_4)
\end{align}
where $|h_4|<h_3<h_2<h_1<h$. In the end, this means that
$$
I-S=\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt-\frac{b-a}6·(f(a)+4f(\tfrac{a+b}2)+f(b))
=
\frac1{90}·\left(\tfrac{b-a}2\right)^5·f^{(4)}(a+\theta(b-a))
$$
with $θ\in(0,1)$. Thus the sign of $I-S$ depends on the sign of the 4th derivative, and it is only definite if the 4th derivative has constant sign over the interval. Under constant sign, this gives a stable inequality for all subdivisions of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Find a polynomial which matches $f$ at $-h, 0, h$ and $f'$ at $0$. It will have order 3 and the error term has order 4. More importantly, the polynomial factor has fixed sign, so you can pull out the fourth derivative from the integral using the mean value theorem of integration. Extend the result to an arbitrary interval in the usual manner.

Comment: Why can you match $f'$ at zero in the context of Simpson integration? (The more normal interpolation error for Simpson's rule does not have a fixed sign, but the "weight" is odd, so that it has integral zero, which allows an alternate approach to the analysis.)

Comment: Actually I think I see it: the integral of the polynomial interpolant for Simpson's rule is the same as that obtained by adding another point (by symmetry), which by a limit argument also implies it is the same as the Hermite interpolant which matches at $-h,0,h$ and matches the derivative at $0$. Then the error for this Hermite-type rule, which is just another way of deriving the same formula as the Simpson rule, fits into the case with a fixed sign which allows the MVT argument.

Comment: This was my first line of reasoning. I have nodes at $\ pm h$ and $\pm \epsilon$. Later I understood that the error analysis which we do for Taylor's formula, Lagrange and Hermite interpolation also applies here and so I could save the limiting argument at the cost an extra error analysis.